# Django import-export fields

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I have a short question about django-import-export. In my model I have choice list:

```
STATE_CHOICES = ((NEW_STATE, u'New'),
                 (DELIVERED_STATE, u'Delivered'),          
                 (LOST_STATE, u'Lost'),
```

And method that handles mapping choices for names

```
@staticmethod
def get_status_name_by_status(status):
    return next((s[1] for s in MyModel.STATE_CHOICES if s[0] == status), 'Uknown')
```

I want to import/export some data

```
class MyModelResource(resources.ModelResource):
    status = fields.Field(column_name='status', attribute='order',
                          widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Order, 'status'))
```

I want to use my get_status_name_by_status method so the choices will be converted to names. But there is no possibility to use method here, only fields are allowed. Any tip how this can be done ?

Comment: Ok, I know how to solve it - just build a new django-import-export widget with proper formatting in render method :)

Comment: I have the same problem, can you write the code, how did you solved this issue? with "def dehydrate" ?

Comment: This is my question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39674976/django-import-export-choices-field), can you help, @hebius ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use 'get_FOO_display' to achieve this in the Django Admin:

```
class MyModelResource(resources.ModelResource):
    status = fields.Field(
        attribute='get_status_display',
        column_name=_(u'Status')
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

A hack method to realize this quickly, just configure `_choice_fields` to your choices fields, that's it.

```
import import_export
from import_export import resources


class MyModelResource(resources.ModelResource):
    _choice_fields = [
        'field_a', 'field_b',
    ]
    for _field_name in _choice_fields:
        locals()[_field_name] = import_export.fields.Field(
            attribute='get_%s_display' % _field_name,
            column_name=MyModel._meta.get_field(_field_name).verbose_name
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want import and export having different field inside Django import-export.

```
class CommonResourcesClass(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = None

class ExportResourcesClass(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = None

class ModelAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, ImportExportActionModelAdmin):
    list_display = ()
    resource_class = CommonResourcesClass
    def get_export_resource_class(self):
        return ExportResourcesClass
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all data can be easily extracted from an object/model attribute. In order to turn complicated data model into a (generally simpler) processed data structure, dehydrate_fieldname method should be defined:

```
class MyModelResource(resources.ModelResource):
    status_name = fields.Field()

    def dehydrate_status_name(self, myModel):
        MyModel.get_status_name_by_status(myModel.status)
```