# How to Import from Import-Export(Admin integration) Django with choices?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-import-export

I have a model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
TITLE = (
    ('Title_Mr', ('Mr')),
    ('Title_Ms', ('Ms')),
)
Name = models.CharField(max_length = 25, default = '')
Title = models.CharField(max_length = 32, choices = TITLE, blank=True, null = True)
...
```

with choices and with the Import-Export feature, I want to import students, who have "Mr" or "Ms" as title values.

What I tried was from this answer
[Django import-export choices field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39674976/django-import-export-choices-field)

but apparently this is for exporting?
What to do if I want to import it. Here is my resources.py

```
from import_export import resources, fields
```

from main.models import Schulungsteilnehmer

```
class StudentsResource(resources.ModelResource):
    Title = fields.Field(attribute='get_Title_display', column_name=('Title'))
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        exclude=('id',)
        import_id_fields = ('StudentID',)
```

I can import without problem, but the choicefields are empty, when I click on a student in Admin panel to edit for example.
how can I save the values as choice selection values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation for choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices):

> The first element in each tuple is the actual value to be set on the model, and the second element is the human-readable name.

So in your case, 'Title_Mr' or 'Title_Ms' is going to be the value stored in the database.

This means that you would be able to import successfully if you defined your `Title` field in `Resource` as follows:

```py
title = fields.Field(attribute='title', column_name='Title')
```

(I've made field names lower-case according to [style guidelines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style))

1. `attribute` is the attribute on the Model class which is going to be set.
2. `column_name` is the name of the header in the import file.
3. This will only work if the data in the import file matches the `choices` declaration (e.g. 'Title_Mr')

However, you said the source data is either 'Mr' or 'Ms'.  To solve this, the easiest way would be to make 'Mr' and 'Ms' the values of the `choices` declaration:

```py
TITLE = (
    ('Mr', ('Mr')),
    ('Ms', ('Ms')),
)
```

But if this is not possible, then you will have to create a [custom widget](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html), which can parse the source data (e.g. 'Mr') and translate it to the correct value (e.g. 'Title_Mr').

For help with creating custom widgets, there are examples in the [source](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/widgets.py).

Comment: This answer solved my problem. Using TITLE=(('Mr',('Mr'),('Ms',('Ms')) works perfeclty. Imported data and title is shown. Thank you very much, I really apprecciate it!
Will mark answer as "Solved my problem".Thank you again for your quick help!